# multi function symbols in ELF library file

Tags: linux, elf

When i dump symbols in libmpich.a, i got this:

```
$ nm /usr/MPICH-install/lib/libmpich.a  | grep PMPI_File_open
00000000 T PMPI_File_open
     U PMPI_File_open
```

Can anyone explain this, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain this

The `libmpich.a` contains at least two object files. One of these defines the function (`T`). The other one references it (`U`).

You can see this by running:

```
nm -A /usr/MPICH-install/lib/libmpich.a  | grep PMPI_File_open
```